# PHP why does my function return twice the result of the array with different keys?

Tags: php, function

I've a problem with one of my function in PHP.
It returns the result two times with different keys…
I want the result only one time without the number keys.

This query and function returns the following array:

```
<?php
#The query
$typo = GetRowsParams("SELECT * FROM glyphs WHERE g_OK=1");  

#The function   
function GetRowsParams($requete, $params = array())
{
global $bdd;
$stmt = $bdd->prepare($requete) or die(print_r($req->errorinfo()));;
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $result;
}
?>


# The Array
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [g_ID] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [g_name] => zero_Nagar.svg
    [1] => zero_Nagar.svg
    [g_height] => 1174
    [2] => 1174
    [g_width] => 352
    [3] => 352
    [g_tag] => Test
    [4] => Test
    [g_u_ID] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [g_path] => 02uploads/Test/zero_Nagar.svg
    [6] => 02uploads/Test/zero_Nagar.svg
    [g_path_PNG] => 02uploads/Test/zero_Nagar.png
    [7] => 02uploads/Test/zero_Nagar.png
    [g_OK] => 1
    [8] => 1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [g_ID] => 2
    [0] => 2
    [g_name] => A
    Nagar.svg [1] => A
            …
            …
```

Why each row is displayed twice with a different key? Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your help…

Comment: your fetsch all have to use the `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: i think there is no mistake. result set always have the values in this way so you can fetch your result either using column names or their indexes.

Comment: @silly: he's using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), not the mysql extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because by default php returns an array where all data has a textual AND a numeric index.
To keep only the textual index, passe PDO::FETCH_ASSOC in the fechAll function like that :
`stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 2):

Add the argument PDO::FETCH_ASSOC like so:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

(You can see the different fetch styles here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the [PDOStatement::fetch methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).   The first argument is a "fetch style," which defaults to fetching an array that looks like the above.  If you just want an array that maps field names to valuse, use:

```
$result = $bdd.fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```