# PHP not fetching correct data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP. I am working on a project and tying to learn PHP. But I am facing a hectic problem which i don't know why this happening. I have a table in database name **gift_items** And I am trying to fetch data of that table through PHP code. But when run the query in php and my browser show me some data not the complete data from data base.

Here is my **ServerConnection.php**

```
<?php  

$Server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';


$database = 'db_gifters';


$connection = mysqli_connect($Server,$username,$password);

if($connection)
{
    mysqli_select_db($connection,$database);
}
else
{
    echo "Could not connect to server";
}


?>
```

And part of php code in index.php where i am actually running the query.

```
<?php 
    $Listquery = "select giftname, gifttype from gift_items order by 
    gifttype,giftname";                                                    

    $gifttype_query = "select distinct gifttype from gift_items";                                                    

    $ListqueryResult = mysqli_query($connection,$Listquery);                                                    

    $gifttype_queryResult = mysqli_query($connection,$gifttype_query);                                                    

    $Listresult = mysqli_fetch_array($ListqueryResult);                                                    

    $gifttype_result = mysqli_fetch_array($gifttype_queryResult);                                                    

    foreach ($gifttype_result as $value)                                                     
    {
        echo $value;
    }
?>
```

The output is as given below: Its gives me the output of same data twice instead of two different data values. As given
[image]

Here i am also attaching the screen shoot of result in database with same query adn it gives me accurate result but in php code its gives me same value twice as output.

[image]
Can someone resolve this issue or tell me what is the actual problem in my script code ??? is there any logical error.??

Comment: Also, please do *not* abuse the snippet tools. That is for HTML/CSS/Javascript *only*.

Comment: Fine. But I just used it for better understating. What the actual problem is.

Comment: Output $connection->error Where #Grumpy ??

Comment: i dont understand why does it print twice

Comment: change `$gifttype_result = mysqli_fetch_array($gifttype_queryResult);`  to `$gifttype_result = mysqli_fetch_array($gifttype_queryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);  `

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gifttype_queryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {  echo $row['gifttype']; }`

Comment: I tried it now it gives me only one time output but not the complete output. Output should be Holidays & Occasions. But instead it gives only occasions. That is actual problem

Comment: Thanks  Spectarion. This help me to solve problem with while loop. But how to do this with foreach loop. ???

Comment: `The mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.`. Basically, "Fetch row by row until you run out of result rows". To be honest, I don't know why it wont work with `foreach`. We need help from someone with bigger knowledge.

Comment: Fine. BTW Thanks, That helped me alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the data as an Associative Array rather than an Indexed Array. It will solve the issue.

There is another post although using PDO that explains the reason for this: [PHP why does my function return twice the result of the array with different keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517063/php-why-does-my-function-return-twice-the-result-of-the-array-with-different-key)

In this case just to each query you want to get the array from.

mysqli_fetch_array([ RESULT VARIABLE HERE ],MYSQLI_ASSOC)

```
$Listresult = mysqli_fetch_array($ListqueryResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);                                                    

$gifttype_result = mysqli_fetch_array($gifttype_queryResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);                                                    

foreach($gifttype_result as $value)                                                     
{
    echo $value['gifttype'];
}
```

More information can be read here: [Assoc. Array Fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
 courtesy of PHP.net

Comment: when i run this code it gives error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'gifttype' in "
at
echo $value['gifttype'];

Comment: It usually means your trying to use a string as an array. 
before the foreach loop var_dump($Listresult) and var_dump($gifttype_result) and show your results on here.